# Does flock() only apply to the current method?

Tags: php, methods, file-locking, flock

Does the `flock()` function only work if it is used within the same method that the code is executed?

For example, in the following code, the lock is successful:

```
public function run()
{
    $filePointerResource = fopen('/tmp/lock.txt', 'w');
    if (flock($filePointerResource, LOCK_EX)) {
        sleep(10);
    } else {
        exit('Could not get lock!');
    }
}
```

However, in the following code, the lock is unsuccessful:

```
public function run()
{
    if ($this->lockFile()) {
        sleep(10);
    } else {
        exit('Could not get lock!');
    }
}

private function lockFile()
{
    $filePointerResource = fopen('/tmp/lock.txt', 'w');
    return flock($filePointerResource, LOCK_EX);
}
```

I haven't seen any documentation on this, so I am puzzled by this behavior. I am using php version 5.5.35.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue with your class based attempt is that when the `lockFile` method finishes the `$filePointerResource` goes out of scope and that is probably what is releasing the lock

This works which sort of supports that theory

```
<?php

class test {
    public function run()
    {
        $fp = fopen('lock.txt', 'w');
        if ($this->lockFile($fp)) {
            echo 'got a lock'.PHP_EOL;
            sleep(5);
        } 
        /*
         * Not going to do anything as the attempt to lock EX will
         * block until a lock can be gained 

        else {
            exit('Could not get lock!'.PHP_EOL);
        }
        */
    }

    private function lockFile($fp)
    {
        return flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
    }
}

$t = new test();
$t->run();
```

So if you want to lock the file over more than one call to a class method it might be better to keep the filehandle as a class property, then it will remain in scope as long as the class is instantiated and in scope.

```
<?php

class test {
    private $fp;

    public function run()
    {
        $this->fp = fopen('lock.txt', 'w');
        if ($this->lockFile()) {
            echo 'got a lock'.PHP_EOL;
            sleep(5);
        } 
        /*
         * Not going to do anything as the attempt to lock EX will
         * block until a lock can be gained 

        else {
            exit('Could not get lock!'.PHP_EOL);
        }
        */
    }

    private function lockFile()
    {
        return flock($this->fp, LOCK_EX);
    }
}

$t = new test();
$t->run();
```

Comment: Wow, this explains it. Thank you.